# Lucene Sentence Search

Tags: java, lucene

Is it possible to search for a phrase of the kind ***Searching is fun***, in Lucene?

When I try to search with this, Lucene ends up looking for the word ***fun*** alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a QueryParser object to parse your query, you can configure it to automatically assume the '+' operator that Aku spoke of in his answer (sorry Aku for not simply commenting, but comments apparently don't support code formatting). For example:

```
String defaultField = ...;
Analyzer analyzer = ...;
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(defaultField, analyzer);

queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);

Query query = queryParser.parse("Searching is fun");
```

Comment: is there any way to do this with pylucene/python?

Answer (score 3):

Try to put in in quotes: *"Searching is fun"* or add '+' to required words *+Searching +fun*

See "[Lucene - Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html)" for available options