# Using Lucene MultiFieldQueryParser for multiple required fields

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I'm trying to use MultiFieldQueryParser to execute the following search:

contents:hello world priority:high

i.e., I *only* want to see documents returned which contain the words 'hello' and 'world' and which have a priority of 'high'. The default behaviour for MultiFieldQueryParser appears to return anything which either contains contents:hello world OR priority:high - I can't figure out how to change this.

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Lucene match all words in query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450547/how-to-make-lucene-match-all-words-in-query)

Answer (score 1):

MultiFieldQuery is used when you want to search a term across multiple fields. What you are looking for is a simple Boolean query with two clauses. A query as follows should work.

```
+(+contents:hello +contents:world) +priority:high
```

Here you have one boolean query with to Occur.MUST clauses one which is, in turn, a boolean query two clauses and another is a term query.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default operator for the parser via `setDefaultOperator` method.

An Example:

```
...
Analyzer userTermsAnalyzer = searchFactory.getAnalyzer(MyEntity.class);
MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, new String[]{"text"}, userTermsAnalyzer);
queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
Query taskQuery = queryParser.parse("contents:hello world priority:high");
```